# Glade 3.36 - button label appears outside when include a image to it

Tags: gtk, glade

I'm trying to put and image or icon on top of the label of a button. When I try to do that the label appears outside the button, like it was pushed down by the image or some spacing. I'm only usign the Glade desinger and css, no gtk code yet.

I appretiate any help,
Thanks in advance.

[label outside the button, it should be inside the button below the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMlcj.png)

UPDATE:
Files of the Glade project:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d332857710487b2acef9429eaf986a7e20200607220022/8053a10764e7bf59dbfab65a169c6daf20200607220022/63adbe

Comment: I think it's best that you paste the (relevant bits) of the XML here, since it's quite hard to know what's  going on otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The issues seem to be related to the bottom alignment. if you change the vertical alignment to fill or anything other than baseline it seems to be working.

```
                      <object class="GtkButton" id="MAIN_ID_BUTTON_PASSWORD">
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">SENHA</property>
                    <property name="name">button_main</property>
                    <property name="width_request">72</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                    <property name="image">image1</property>
                    <property name="relief">none</property>
                    <property name="image_position">top</property>
                    <property name="always_show_image">True</property>
                  </object>
```

it seems to be some space-related issue. I don't know the exact reason behind this behaviour but after some trial and error it seems like if you position the image over the label and set valign -> baseline the image seems to be taking the top baseline and the label seems to get positioned below the baseline(guessing that the behavioural problem is related to the label).(https://blog.gtk.org/2017/06/)